# how to create Bootstrap buttons on mobile devices responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, drop-down-menu, responsive-design, bootstrap-modal

in bootstrap simple button display like this. on mobile devices how to create all button in drop down list as click on button  ??

Desktop view like this:
[image: desktop]
Mobile image mobile view like this:
[image: mobile]

Comment: Do you want to do like these pictures?

Comment: in desktop simple button created but on mobile view time all button display in one drop down button .

Comment: What have you tried? Where is the code?

Have you ever read http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do same as desktop and mobile then you have to add desktop and mobile class both. I mean that what you want, you have to add these class. If you want four design will be same, then you have to add four design class at a time.

> xs (for phones)
>
> sm (for tablets)
>
> md (for desktops)
>
> lg (for larger desktops)

```
<div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2">
                <button>
                    DROPDOWN1
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2">
                <button>
                    DROPDOWN1
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2">
                <button>
                    DROPDOWN1
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2">
                <button>
                    DROPDOWN1
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2">
                <button>
                    DROPDOWN1
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2">
                <button>
                    DROPDOWN1
                </button>
            </div>

        </div>
```

**Or you can use just col-xs-2**

After your comment:

If you want to want all buttons by one button then you have to use `navbar`.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: `col-md-2 col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2` is equivalent to `col-xs-2`. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know this before.

Comment: hey black i say desktop devices all right but on mobile devices view time only one button view and other all button is view  on click that button .like as :http://osvaldas.info/examples/drop-down-navigation-touch-friendly-and-responsive/?work       this is menu but i need button on that

Comment: Here is given your solution: http://osvaldas.info/drop-down-navigation-responsive-and-touch-friendly

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do same as desktop and mobile then you have to add desktop and mobile class both. I mean that what you want, you have to add these class. If you want four design will be same, then you have to add four design class at a time.

xs (for phones)

sm (for tablets)

md (for desktops)

lg (for larger desktops)